# How can I checked if the visitor is logged in from a plush template? Using the go Buffalo framework

Tags: go, buffalo

How can I check if a visitor is logged in from within a template using the Go Buffalo web framework? Specifically, I am working on a project that utilizes the Buffalo framework and I need to be able to determine if a user is currently logged in or not, and I would like to do this within one of my templates. Are there any built-in methods or functions provided by Buffalo that can be used to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I can use `current_user`, like this

```
<div class="auth-center">
  <%= if (current_user) { %>
    <h1><%= current_user.email %></h1>
    <a href="/signout" data-method="delete">sign out</a>
  <% } else { %>
    <a href="/signin" class="btn btn-primary">sign in</a>
    <a href="/users/new" class="btn btn-success">register</a>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: `current_user` will only be available if it was set on the context before like `c.Set("current_user", user)`. So be sure have set the user somewhere